# make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop. make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: scripts, windows, video, files

I have little experience coding and trying to setup up Python vmaf on Ubuntu using https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/blob/master/resource/doc/python.md#linux instructions.

up to the stage of Clean build the binary by: make clean; make

However this command comes up with make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Any advice to get around this error ?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't `cd` to the vmaf directory before running the command

Comment: I have now cd to the vmaf however now this error is appearing PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/c/Users/Alice/.venv/vmaf-master/libvmaf/build/include/libvmaf/version.h~'
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 2